Sphinx version is not shown with read-the-docs theme
I'm using:

Sphinx v8.1.3 next to the "sphinx_rtd_theme"
I'm not hosting this docs anywhere

Usually (with an earlier sphinx version for python 2.7) sphinx showed the "version" above the search bar by simply indicating version and release in the conf.py

But that seems not to work like that anymore, any idea on how to achieve that? Or is this no longer part of the theme and I would need to and edit the layout.html?

It appears that a single version has been replaced with a version selector that works only on RTD in a recent version of sphinx_rtd_theme.
See the option version_selector.

Display a version selector below the title. This feature makes usage of Read the Docs Addons for this, so it’s required the documentation to be hosted on Read the Docs. It only appears when there are more than 1 active version.

So you can either override the theme, downgrade to an earlier version of the theme, or select a different theme.

Oh that is so sad... why would they do that :c
Anyway, thanks for your response at least now I know its not my fault. Thx!

Check if version and release are properly set in conf.py: In Sphinx, the version and release are typically defined in the conf.py configuration file. The version represents the short version number, and the release can be the full version number (e.g., 1.0.0).
